# Database more efficient way storing the referral to 1'st table in every line in the 2'nd table

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have 2 tables on my DB

[image]

I want to avoid the **"account ref"** for every line in dates table, is there a way to keep fast fetching and reduce memory ?

I uses postgresql as DB with Django and Python.

Comment: The relation column is part of the SQL concept, this this is what allows you to do a faster fetching as you let the DB engine do the actual records collection. and it also saves space in the DB. 

The only other way is to merge the two tables into one, which may be relevant for small tables (even if conceptually wrong), but if you need to extend the accounts table later on, it means duplicating lots data points that were to be part of the accounts table only, for every row that the account is listed on in the 2ne table

Comment: Postgres is a *relational* database, for this model the column `account_ref` is what defines the *relation*. You will find that not only is `account_ref* necessary, but that in most cases it will be defined an required and without it the row **will not be allowed in the database**.

Comment: @MenyIssakov how can it be merged to one table ? as date is multiple time while user is once .?

Comment: It means duplicating the user values across multiple rows.
If you ask me, it's not the way to go, as it kind of breaks the schema of the "relational" DB concept, but hey, you can do whatever you want with your DB